# Retrieve data by Ignoring null values and header row from csv file

Tags: csv, groovy, soapui

Working on `Groovy Script` in soapui 5.3.0 and facing the below issue while extracting the values from file to a list.
Purpose of below code is, the list retrieved has to be compared with another list with valid values only.

Attaching the code snippet and the sample csv file for reference.

code to retrieve the values:

```
def DBvalue= context["csvfile"] //csv file containing the data
def count= context["dbrowcount"] //here the rowcount is 23
for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
    def lines= ""
    lines= DBvalue.text.split('\n')
    list<string> rows = lines.collect{it.split(';)}
    log.info "list is"+rows
}
```

Sample CSV file on which am working contains 600 column of data with 23 rows

```
abc;null;1;2;3;5;8;null
cdf;null;2;3;6;null;5;6
hgf;null;null;null;jr;null;II
```

Currently my code is fetching the below output:

```
[[abc,null,1,2,3,5,8,null]]
[[abc,null,1,2,3,5,8,null]]
[[abc,null,1,2,3,5,8,null]]
```

Desired output:

```
[1,2,3,5,8]
[2,3,6,5,6]
[jr,II]
```

Comment: am stuck, can anyone help please

Comment: SD31, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: @Rao: the code is printing all the rows except 1st one. Also, my desired output was [1,2,3,5,8], but am currently getting displayed with [abc,1,2,3,5,8]. Is there a possible way to get the 1st row and omit this 1st index i.e abc or abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able achieve it with below, and follow in-line comments.

```
//Provide your file path; change if needed
def file = new File('/tmp/test.csv')

//To hold all the rows
def list = []

//Change delimiter if needed
def delimiter = ';'

file.readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index) {
        //Get the row data by split, filter
        def lineData = line.split(delimiter).findAll { 'null' != it && it}
        log.info lineData
        list << lineData
    }
}

//Print all the row data
log.info list
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton @Rao.. it omits the 1st row. its printing the rest of the rows

Comment: That is what you wanted right? By the appreciate if you can accept it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: no @Rao, I didn't want to skip the 1st row. its missing the whole row of data. If you could help on this, would be really great..

Comment: @SD31, i have added the data input and output. Please compare it with yours. Do you have headers in your csv file? Otherwise, you can just omit `if` **condition** and keep the inside statements as is.

Comment: it worked now. my file didn't have headers. its only with data. Thanks a lot for your help :)